# File size 5622620 less than minimum allowed for this API: ''20000000', Python Box-SDK

Tags: python, box, boxsdk

While uploading files to box it gives an error says File size is less than required. Here is my code:

```
import os
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client
import schedule
import time

directory = '/videos'


def save_video():
    retval = os.getcwd()
    help = (retval)
    os.chdir(help + directory)
    retval = os.getcwd()

    config = JWTAuth.from_settings_file('box_config.json')
    client = Client(config)

    for file_name in os.listdir(retval):
        print(file_name)
        if file_name == 'box_config.json':
            continue
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
        print(file_name)
        folder_id = '144613233618'

        upload_session = client.folder(folder_id=folder_id).create_upload_session(file_size, file_name)
        print('Created upload session {0} with chunk size of {1} bytes'.format(upload_session.id, upload_session.part_size))

        chunked_upload = upload_session.get_chunked_uploader(file_name)
        uploaded_file = chunked_upload.start()
        print('File "{0}" uploaded to Box with file ID {1}'.format(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file.id))

        os.remove(file_name)



schedule.every().day.at("11:34").do(save_video)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I will upload more than one file as sequence and some file's size could be less than 20000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunked uploads have more overhead, so they only allow it for files larger than 20MB.  For smaller files, use the normal `upload` API.  In fact, they recommend the normal `upload` up to 50MB.

Comment: Actually, in the normal situation, I would upload files larger than 1GB, but they can probably be even less than 20MB, so as far as I understand there is no way to use chunked uploads with files smaller than 20MB and larger than 50MB together. Thank you.

Comment: Well, then, check the size beforehand.  `if` statements are easy.